# chart.renderTo doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, rendering

I'm trying to dynamically create highcharts on the same page in a bootstrap carousel.

I have a function "createChart" like this:

```
createChart(questiontitle, answers);

function createChart(questiontitle, answers){
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); // Create new chart with general options
    chart.renderTo(container);
    for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        categories.push(answers[i].Text);
    }
    console.log(categories);
    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
    chart.setTitle({ text: 'eerzera' });
    // redraw chart
    chart.redraw();
}
```

I have a div like this:

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

As you can see I have "chart.renderTo" but I always get the same error:

> Highcharts Error #13
>
> Rendering div not found
>
> This error occurs if the chart.renderTo option is misconfugured so
>   that Highcharts is unable to find the HTML element to render the chart
>   in.

My variable options is like this:

```
var options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Population (millions)',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' millions'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -40,
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            shadow: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Year 1800',
            data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Year 1900',
            data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
        }, {
            name: 'Year 2008',
            data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
        }]
    }
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your goal is to keep this dynamic, by being able to build multiple charts with multiple renderTo's but using the same options, you can do it like this:

change

```
function createChart(questiontitle, answers){
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); 
    chart.renderTo(container);
```

to:

```
function createChart(questiontitle, answers){
    chart = $('#container').highcharts(options);
```

or, if not using jQuery,

```
function createChart(questiontitle, answers){
    options.chart.renderTo = 'container';
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Answer (score 6):

In case someone stumbles on this while Googling, when you specific the element in `renderTo`, you shouldn't include the `#` if that element is an ID.

If you have this element `<div id="graph-container"></div>`

This fails:
`renderTo: '#graph-container'`

This works:
`renderTo: 'graph-container'`

[Reference to the Highcharts docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.renderTo)

Answer (score 4):

Something like this: `chart.renderTo(container);` doesn't exists in Highcharts.

To set `renderTo` use options:

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be facing the same problem that i was.
Try to put your highchart script right after your div's declaration just like in the example bellow so it can recognize your div's id:

```
<head>
    <title>HighCharts :D</title>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }]
    });
    myChart.renderTo('container');

</script>
</body>
```